# jquery: find element whose id has a particular pattern

Tags: asp.net, jquery, master-pages, find, element

I am trying to find a span element who has an id in a particular pattern. Its main use is to find certain elements rendered by an asp.net (aspx) page which is derived from a master page.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
$('span').each(function(){
   if( $(this).attr('id').match(/pattern/) ) {
        // your code goes here
   }
});
```

problem solved.

Answer (score 177):

Building on the accepted answer:

It depends on what kind of pattern you're looking for.  If your pattern is something like "MasterPageElement_CheckBox_4443", "MasterPageElement_CheckBox_4448", etc. then you could also use:

```
$("span[id^=MasterPageElement_CheckBox]")
```

There are 3 built-in attribute selectors for simple patterns:

```
$("span[id^=foo]")
```

That selector matches all spans that have an `id` attribute and it starts with `foo` (e.g. `fooblah`)

```
$("span[id$=foo]")
```

That selector matches all spans that have an `id` attribute and it ends with `foo` (e.g. `blahfoo`).

```
$("span[id*=foo]")
```

That selector matches all spans that have an `id` attribute and it has `foo` somewhere within in it (e.g. `blahfooblah`).

Comment: Links: [*= pattern](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/), [$= pattern](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) and [^= pattern](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old post, but additional information can help future developers who stumble across this. :) To add on to what @cdmckay mentioned, you can combine the attribute selectors to achieve "begins with X and ends with Y".

```
$("input[id^=inp][id$=_AddItem]")
```

This will match id "inp1_AddItem", "inp2_AddItem", "inp3_AddItem", etc.