# Jquery selector to get all select dropdowns with ID pattern

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-selectors

What is the simplest way to iterate through all select drop downs with ID's matching a pattern using jquery. for example:

```
<select id="begin_1_end">...</select>

<select id="begin_32_end">...</select>

<select id="begin_42_end">...</select>

<select id="dontgetme_2_end">...</select>

<select id="begin_12_dontgetme">...</select>
```

to iterate through the first 3 selects only.

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487792/jquery-find-element-whose-id-has-a-particular-pattern/1487882

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this with [attribute-starts-with-selector/](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('select[id^="begin"]').each(function () {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

or you could use  [attribute-ends-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
$('select[id$="end"]').each(function () {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

**Update**

To select the first 3 you can use `:lt(3)` like this

```
$('select[id^="begin"]:lt(3)').each(function () {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/jZN8D/)

**Update**

To combine the selectors you can do this

```
$('select[id^="begin"][id$="end"]').each(function () {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/3zwcj/1/)

If you want to select an element with id that starts with begin **OR** end you can do this using `,` to get two different selectors

```
$('select[id^="begin"],select[id$="end"]').each(function () {
    //                ^
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/3zwcj/2/)

Comment: thanks. how do you combine both the beginning and end patterns? please see the updated question. thnx. sometimes the beginning pattern matches but not the ending one.

Comment: In your updated question you want to select only the first three, then one of the recent updates in my answer should work. Have you tested? @RayS.

Answer (score 3):

use attribute [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), then use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate through them

```
$('select[id^=begin_]').each(function(){...})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
  $("select[id^='begin_'").each(function(){
  //your stuff
  })
```