# Find elements with jquery selector and regex

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

I've got several input boxes like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_item[500]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_item[10]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_item[2]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_item[1]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_item[]" />
```

So I'm using the following regex pattern `checkbox_item\[\d+\]` which works nicely in my regex tester but I cannot get it to work with Jquery.  This is my Jquery code:

```
console.log($("input:regex(name, /checkbox_item\[\d+\]/)").length);
```

I was expecting 4 but instead got 28!

Can somebody shed any light on this?

Thanks

Comment: So do you use the [following regex filter for jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/)?

Comment: ... if you do, try to remove slashes `/` before and after regular expression in the selector, i.e. `:regex(name, checkbox_item\[\d+\])`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095607/jquery-selector-to-get-all-select-dropdowns-with-id-pattern/

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think jQuery natively supports regular expressions in selectors in that way.

But you could use the [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Attribute Starts](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) with like

```
console.log($("input[type=checkbox][name^='checkbox_item']").length)
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SVEtM/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i understand it corretly, but you want to get the total elements that begins with checkbox_item?

```
$("input[name^=checkbox_item]").length
```

This will give you the total elements that begins with checkbox_item.

more info about this selector [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).