# Creating multiple click events in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Working on a reusable javascript control at the moment that will display a list of 6 people and when you click their name a popup shows up with a rating of their skills. I'm generating most of the html using JQuery and so far its works. The people are read in from a JSON file and currently there are 6, but I would like it so that no matter how many people are in the JSON file each one will have their own `onclick` function. Here's how the click events are set up:

```
document.getElementById("0").onclick = function ()
    {
     overlay.style.display = "block";
     sk.style.display = "block";
     setSkills(0)
    };
    document.getElementById("1").onclick = function ()
    {
     overlay.style.display = "block";
     sk.style.display = "block";
     setSkills(1)
    };
    document.getElementById("2").onclick = function ()
    {
     overlay.style.display = "block";
     sk.style.display = "block";
     setSkills(2)
    };
    document.getElementById("3").onclick = function ()
    {
     overlay.style.display = "block";
     sk.style.display = "block";
     setSkills(3)
    };
    document.getElementById("4").onclick = function ()
    {
     overlay.style.display = "block";
     sk.style.display = "block";
     setSkills(4)
    };
    document.getElementById("5").onclick = function ()
    {
     overlay.style.display = "block";
     sk.style.display = "block";
     setSkills(5)
    };
```

I feel like hard coding these in defeats the reusability of the project, is there any way to dynamically generate this code for `n` number of elements?

Here's the html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Player.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
    <header>

    </header>

    <div id="container">
    <div id="overLay"></div>
    <div id="skills">

    </div>
    </div>
    <script>

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the html code generated by JQuery:

```
var data;
var ulClass
var liId
var html
var skill
var playerClass
var x = 'container'

$.getJSON("players.json", function(json)
{
     var overlay = document.getElementById("overLay");
     var sk = document.getElementById("skills")
     data = json

    ulClass = "list"
    liId = "listItems" 
    html ='<div id="' + liId  + '" class="' + ulClass + '">';
    skills = '<ul  class="' + ulClass + '">';
    playerClass = "player"

   $(data).each(function(i)
   {

        console.log(x)
        html += '<p id="' +  i + '">' + data[i].Name + "</p>";


   });
   html += '<hr>'
   html += "</div>";
   $('#container').append(html);
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Sorry will show you the html code now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing much of your code:

```
for(var index = 0; index < 6; index++)
{
    (function(picked){
        document.getElementById("dontusenumbersfirst" + picked).onclick = function ()
        {
            overlay.style.display = "block";
            sk.style.display = "block";
            setSkills(picked)
        };
    })(index)
}
```

Contain it in a for-loop and then contain it in an anonymous function with a parameter.

If you skip the anonymous function part, you'll be referencing "index" for all 6 listener functions, which ended with the value of 5.

Comment: I implemented your solution and I got an error as id seems to be null.

Comment: I don't think you can use a number for the first character of your element id.

Comment: added a string first like you said but it still returns null, ideally the for loop should be embedded in the `.each()` method because thats where the id's are being generated?

Comment: Run it after `$('#container').append(html);`

Those elements don't exist in the DOM until you append them.

Comment: You can also create elements as jQuery variables and manipulate/append them. Way better in terms of readability and usability. [link](https://coderwall.com/p/evmqoa/creating-dom-elements-with-jquery-in-a-more-elegant-way)

Answer (score 0):

You can attach one common class in loop where you create HTML for people something like `.people-profile` and then use a click handler for that class like,

```
$('.people-profile').on('click', function() {
  var selectedPersonId = $(this).attr('id');

  overlay.style.display = "block";
  sk.style.display = "block";      

  setSkills(parseInt(selectedPersonId));
});
```

I think should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the li elements using a for loop.

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#list li');

for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    this.onclick = function(){
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    sk.style.display = "block";
        setSkills(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the ID's for your people elements in a particular pattern and follow this SO for selecting and binding click events on all the people elements [Jquery selector to get all select dropdowns with ID pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095607/jquery-selector-to-get-all-select-dropdowns-with-id-pattern)