# Jquery advanced filtering of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large list of elements with data attributes.

```
<ul>
   <li data-brandid="1" data-finishid="5" data-typeid="10" data-constructionid="14">
   <li data-brandid="4" data-finishid="1" data-typeid="3" data-constructionid="7">
   <li data-brandid="18" data-finishid="2" data-typeid="1" data-constructionid="4">
   <li data-brandid="7" data-finishid="4" data-typeid="4" data-constructionid="5">
   <li data-brandid="4" data-finishid="8" data-typeid="1" data-constructionid="2">
   <li data-brandid="2" data-finishid="12" data-typeid="2" data-constructionid="16">
</ul>
```

At the top of the page, I have a form with checkboxes for each option for each attribute. They can select multiple options for each data attribute. So, for example, if they selected brandsid's 2 and 5, finishid's 1 and 4, typeid's 4 and 2 and constructionid's 1 and 14 the pseudocode(SQL style) would look  something like this:

```
AND (brandid = 2 OR brandid = 5)
AND (finishid = 1 OR finishid = 4)
AND (typeid = 4 OR typeid= 2)
AND (constructionid = 1 OR 14)
```

But I'm not sure how to turn this into a jquery selector.

Thanks.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ ?

Comment: Use `.filter()` with callback

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Its not that simple. If they select Brand1, Brand2 and Finish1, that means that they want products that are Finish1 that are either Brand1 OR Brand2, not all products are Finish1 OR brand1 OR brand1

Comment: You may need to better/more-clearly explain your requirements for those of us that don't speak SQL (this *definitely* includes me).

Comment: @JackPilowsky I am pretty sure that my answer would help here. Please check it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use patterns in jQuery like this -

```
$('li[data-brandid^=1][data-finishid^=5]')
```

Which looks for those attributes consisting of 1 and 5 correspondingly.

Here is a code snippet you could use -

```js
var choose = function(brandId, finishId, typeid, constructionid){
  // Search through brandid and finishid
  var sel = $('li[data-brandid^=' + brandId + '][data-finishid^='+ finishId +'][data-typeid^='+ typeid +'][data-constructionid^='+ constructionid +']')
  $('div').append(sel);
};

$('#go').on('click', function(){  
  var brandIds = [];
  var constructionIds = [];
  var typeIds = [];
  var finishIds = [];
  
  if($('#brandid').val().indexOf(',') != -1)
    brandIds = $('#brandid').val().split(',');
  
  if($('#finishid').val().indexOf(',') != -1)
    finishIds = $('#finishid').val().split(',');
  
  if($('#typeid').val().indexOf(',') != -1)
    typeIds = $('#typeid').val().split(',');
  
  if($('#constructionid').val().indexOf(',') != -1)
    constructionIds = $('#constructionid').val().split(',');
  
  
      
  $.each(brandIds, function(brInd, brand){
    $.each(finishIds, function(finId, finish){
      $.each(typeIds, function(typeId, type){
        $.each(constructionIds, function(conId, construction){
          choose(brand, finish, type, construction);
        });
      });          
    });    
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Brand ID <input type="text" id="brandid" />
Finish ID <input type="text" id="finishid" />
Type ID <input type="text" id="typeid" />
Construction ID <input type="text" id="constructionid">

<button id="go">Go!</button>
<br/><br/>

Available (Brand - Finish - Type - Construction)
<ul>
  <li data-brandid="1" data-finishid="5" data-typeid="10" data-constructionid="14">1 - 5 - 10 - 14</li>
  <li data-brandid="4" data-finishid="1" data-typeid="3" data-constructionid="7">4 - 1 - 3 - 7</li>
  <li data-brandid="18" data-finishid="2" data-typeid="1" data-constructionid="4">18 - 2 - 1 - 4</li>
  <li data-brandid="7" data-finishid="4" data-typeid="4" data-constructionid="5">7 - 4 - 4 - 5</li>
  <li data-brandid="4" data-finishid="8" data-typeid="1" data-constructionid="2">4 - 8 - 1 - 2</li>
  <li data-brandid="2" data-finishid="12" data-typeid="2" data-constructionid="16">2 - 12 - 2 - 16</li>
</ul>

Selected (Brand - Finish - Type - Construction)
<div id="selected"></div>
```

**EDIT:** For multiple values, using a $.each

Comment: Aswin, Thanks for your answer, but this won't work because users can submit multiple selections for each filter. So, for example, they can select brands 1, 3 and 7.

Comment: How about now? I think ultimately you're gonna have to use the pattern to select

Comment: The pattern? I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: You're gonna want to search for the elements using patterns like this.. [data-brandid^=1][data-finishid^=5][data-typeid^=10][data-constructionid^=4] etc.. Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487792/jquery-find-element-whose-id-has-a-particular-pattern

Comment: @JackPilowsky.. Updated the snippet.. Use comma separated values for each text box.. Let me know if it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a filter like this and its actually quite easy if you know how to start.

We assume that every active filter has a `class="active"`. We furthermore assume that every checkbox has a data-attribute which holds the name of the filter (e.g. `data-filter="brandid"` and a data-attribute which holds the value which should be selected (e.g. `data-value="1"`).

This assumed we can start building the function

```
$items = $('li');

// Whenever a user changes a checkbox we want to filter our data
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){

    // We toggle the active-class to dis/enable our filter
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    // We need an object holding our filters
    var filter = {};
    var $filtered = $items;

    // We select all active filter here and push them to the array
    $('input[type="checkbox"].active').each(function(){

        // When a filter with this type didnt exists in our object we create a new one
        if(filters[$(this).data('filter')] === undefined) filters[$(this).data('filter')] = {};

        // Then we push the filter to our array
        filters[$(this).data('filter')].push($(this).data('value'));

    });

    // We loop through every filter, select all elements which match the
    // filter and apply it to the $filtered selection
    // The items left is the desired collection
    for(var i in filters){

        // For every filter in our object
        // (which can hold multiple filters of one type)
        // we build a selector.
        // We join the selectors using `,` to get an `or`-selection
        selector = filters[i].map(function(value){
            return '[data-'+i+'="'+value+'"]';
        }).join(',');

        // Apply the filter
        $filtered = $filtered.filter(selector);
    }

    // $filtered now holds all elemets left
    // do with this elements what you want

}
```